# What port should be specified in FTP

Tags: android, ftp, numbers, port

Im am converting a program from Basic4PPC to Basic4Android.

That program uses FTP to read a small file from a server. The original program  works very well. Now with Basic4Android reading  a file results in  success = false. FTPConnection closed without indication. I have to specify a port number. The sample code shows 21. Is that port the only one which should work? How to find the correct port number?

Harry

Answer (score 2):

The FTP protocol is defined in [RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) and specifies port 21 for connections, with port 20 used for data transmissions as necessary. Whilst you don't *have* to use port 21 to establish an FTP connection, you should do so unless you have a very good reason to diverge from the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the problem still exists. The log says: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.

Comment: Well, the question was about FTP port assignment, rather than the error you're seeing. Given that Apache is reporting that the connection was closed, the implication is that there *was* a connection - so this isn't about port numbers, it's about how you're establishing the connection, or more precisely how you're closing it. A fast Google gave me a number of hits on that error, and possible solutions (depending on the type of connection you're establishing).

Comment: Sorry, I expected that the port number caused the problem. Meanwhile i found the soluytion: With the FTP server I use the PassiveMode should be set to True